# ¿Como añado al .gitignore un archivo sin extension?

Tags: git, gitignore

Tengo en un directorio un archivo de texto llamado `serie`, sin extensión. ¿Cómo puedo agregarlo al .gitignore?
He probado a añadir `*.` en una linea pero no funciona. Cuando hago *push* en mi repo me lo sigue añadiendo

Se me ha ocurrido que lo podría modificar y guardarlo como un `.txt` pero no se si puedo hacerlo al formar este parte de un archivo de un programa.

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Es una pregunta muy interesante. Te dejo para que pruebes [esta solución](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19023985/3791844) y en caso de que te funcione podes crear una respuesta a tu propia pregunta.

Comment: Me da la impresión por lo que dices, que ya tienes el archivo en el repo de git, por lo que añadirlo en el .gitignore no camba el hecho que ya git lo tiene incorporado. Deberías eliminarlo de git y luego si el .gitignore tendrá sentido.

Comment: agrega `serie` y ya. De todos modos, estás hablando de _push_  y el `.gitignore` no tiene nada que ver con pushing. El `.gitignore` lo único que hace es evitar que el archivo lo puedas _agregar_ **si no se le está haciendo seguimiento**. Si el archivo ya está siendo segudi por git (es decir, ya forma parte de la revisión en ala que estás parado), entonces `.gitignore` no tiene ningún efecto. Y, para redondear la idea, _siempre_ lo que se va a ir en un push es lo que haya en los commits involucrados. No hay forma de enviar un commit de forma parcial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Listo, gracias por el enlace a la pregunta en ingles. Era añadir

```
*
!/**/
!*.*
```

Pero antes de incluir cualquier otra extension, para que no te la deje de ignorar también.

Como dicen, tambien tenia que hacer un `git rm --cached serie` antes de realizar el commit con los cambios en el `.gitignore`